# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, model

I have a problem with models flutter project that I have..
I get an error:

> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String'.
>
> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'Int'.
>
> The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type
> 'String'.

```
class Category {
  final String name;
  final int numOfCourses;
  final String image;

  Category(this.name, this.numOfCourses, this.image);
}

List<Category> categories = categoriesData
    .map((item) => Category(item['name'], item['courses'], item['image']))
    .toList();

var categoriesData = [
  {"name": "Marketing", 'courses': 17, 'image': "assets/images/marketing.png"},
  {"name": "UX Design", 'courses': 25, 'image': "assets/images/ux_design.png"},
  {
    "name": "Photography",
    'courses': 13,
    'image': "assets/images/photography.png"
  },
  {"name": "Business", 'courses': 17, 'image': "assets/images/business.png"},
];
```

error in this part

```
(item['name'], item['courses'], item['image'])
```

thanks for the answers..

Comment: Not entirely sure, but two things spring to mind off the top of my head - 1. should 'courses': instead be "courses": in your Json?  Also, 2. perhaps the item[] variables need to be passed as item['name']! (exclamation mark at the end) for null safety?  (point 2 may not be right ....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart doesn't know what `categoriesData['name']`, `categoriesData['courses']` or `categoriesData['image']` are supposed to be, to tell it, you can use the `as` keyword:

```
categories = categoriesData
    .map((item) => Category(item['name'] as String, item['courses'] as int, item['image'] as String))
    .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the convert helpers in the [flutter_helper_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_helper_utils) package, since the keyword `as` does not always work, especially with `List`, and `Map`, and when you try to use it on double data but use `as int`.
but before that, we need to clean your class with serializable methods
here is a cleaned version of your class:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_helper_utils/flutter_helper_utils.dart';

class Category {
  const Category({
    required this.name,
    required this.numOfCourses,
    required this.image,
  });

  factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Category(
      name: toString1(map['name']),
      numOfCourses: toInt(map['courses']),
      image: toString1(map['image']),
    );
  }

  final String name;
  final int numOfCourses;
  final String image;

  static List<Category> fromList(List<dynamic> list) {
    return list.map((e) => Category.fromJson(toMap(e))).toList();
  }
}
```

then you can use your class like this:

```dart
final categories = Category.fromList(categoriesData);
// or to get single category from map you can.
final category = Category.fromJson(mapData);
```